# How to include libzip library in Xcode project?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, libzip

Currently i am doing unziping a zip file program using libzip library, 
following this link - http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html .
i want to include the library and frame work in my xcode project .

From the demo project that has give in their site , i included the lib directory and tried to link but i am getting a linker error that

ld: framework not found libzip_iOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Actually my task is to include libzip library and unzipping the zip file on click of button . so i know how to access C++ class in objective C , just getting a linker error because of Libzip library.

i am new in xcode is anyone know about how to take library and link in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You just follow these steps -

1- unzip your `library and frame work`.
2- copy into the project.
3- `Add files` in to x-code project.
4- just select the `framework` and Drop in to the `linked framework and libraries` .

May be it will help you, or fell free.

Comment: i unzipped the given file from  http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html  at "Distfiles"but there is no any framework present inside it. only lib directory is present.   If you tel me step by step procedure that will be very very helpfull Abhishek

Comment: you just need to drag and drop in the Xcode , same as files , and 

Drop the file in to the linked framework and libraries section of the xcode

Comment: i dragged and dropped lib directory in my xcode project, which files should i drop in Linked framework ?

Comment: I can't understand you. please explain.

Comment: Hi Abhishek .. i tried to include framework and is it shows all headers, but run time i am getting an error , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728216/libzip-library-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64    -  symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 . , my library is built for ios devices , is it because of that ?

Comment: Did anyone finally solve this? I am not able to add this particular project to Xcode https://libzip.org